# Lightning DataTable onCellChange

Tags: lightning-datatable

I would like to know if there is any way I can do autosave when I change a cell value in the `Lightning:datatable`.

I have gone through the doc https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:datatable/specification but there is not enough detail on the `onCellChange` method.

Answer (score 4):

As you would expect `onCellChange` actions are fired when a table cell's value changes in an inline edit. There's a good example of using this feature [here](https://github.com/garazi/summer2018demo/blob/master/force-app/main/default/aura/cmpDatatable/cmpDatatableHelper.js)

So, here is the setup you do in the component. Note the draftValues are there because that's what `onCellChange` actions return on inline edits.

```
<aura:attribute name="draftValues" type="Object" default="[]"/>
<aura:attribute name="mydata" type="Object"/>
<aura:attribute name="mycolumns" type="List"/>
<aura:attribute name="errors" type="Object" default="[]"/>
<aura:attribute name="saveLocalStorage" type="Boolean" default="false"/>

<lightning:datatable
errors="{! v.errors }"
draftValues="{! v.draftValues }"
data="{! v.mydata }" 
columns="{! v.mycolumns }" 
keyField="Id"
onsave="{! c.handleSave }"
oncellchange="{! c.handleEditCellChange}"
oncancel="{! c.handleCancel }"
onrowaction="{! c.handleRowAction }"
/>
```

the controller is pretty basic. It just calls the handler method

```
 handleEditCellChange: function(cmp, event, helper) {
    helper.handleEditCell(cmp, event);
  },
```

The helper has a bunch going on:

```
handleEditCell: function (cmp, event) {
    var saveLocalStorage = cmp.get('v.saveLocalStorage');
    if (saveLocalStorage) {
        var atomicChange = event.getParam('draftValues');
        var atomicChanges = cmp.get('v.atomicChanges');
        atomicChanges.push(atomicChange);
        cmp.set('v.changeIndex', atomicChanges.length);

        var draftValues = this.getBuildedDraftValues(atomicChanges, atomicChanges.length);

        localStorage.setItem('demo-draft-values', JSON.stringify(atomicChanges));
    }

    if (cmp.get('v.autoSaveEnabled')) {
        this.saveChanges(cmp, draftValues);
    }
},
```