# lightning:datatable event handler when a cell is being edited

Tags: lightning, lightning-datatable

I am using `lightning:datatable` to display data and it has the ability to inline edit.  I was wondering if there's some sort of event handler when a cell is being edited (when the user clicks the pencil icon on the table cell for inline edit)?

The reason I asked is I would like to disable a button outside of the datable during an inline edit.  I looked through the `lightning:datatable` documentation but no luck.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: this solution might be help you, https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/268167/lightning-datatable-oncellchange

Answer (score 1):

You can use `oncellchange` here.

From [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:datatable/documentation) (emphasis mine):

> You can handle the `oncancel`, `oncellchange`, and `onsave` actions when the **cell value changes or is saved**.

Comment: I'm having this problem now.  The oncellchange event - certainly in LWC anyway - only fires when the user blurs away from the edit, ie they click on something other than the input field after making a change.  Does anyone know if we can capture an event when the user actually clicks the pencil icon, or as soon as they type a change?

Comment: @ministe Were you able to find any solution?

Comment: @Shanky yes I just used onchange in addition to oncellchange to handle the two different scenarios!